# Profiling a C# dot net application running on a docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, profiling, monitoring

I was looking out for an open source profiling tool for C# Dot Net that could profile C# dot net code that's running inside a docker container and give out CPU,Disk and network stats to potentially help identify bottlenecks in code.

Any suggestions would be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want an APM tool, which is essentially a production profiler. Many of them also capture deep Docker metrics along with a bunch of other data points. The leaders in this space according to Gartner are AppDynamics (where I work), Dynatrace, and New Relic. There are lots of others which will do what you ask, but they are designed to run in dev and prod. Each of these tools have free versions you could use for your dev environment. Typically Docker metrics aren't going to help you diagnose and optimize code, but the .NET instrumentation sure will :)